# Eclipse plugin to save workspace in repository

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin

Is there a Eclipse plugin to save the workspace in a repository (like SVN) whenever eclipse is closed?  It would be great if it could save the workspace in a zip file like workspace_date.zip for each day.

Comment: Wait.  Are you asking two things?  Do you just want to save a copy of your workspace every day?  Or do you want to commit to SVN every day?  You say "like SVN" - are other source control systems an option?

Comment: Are you running eclipse on Windows, Linux, other?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good.Because we will devolope so many things.If it automatically send to SVN 
then it is difficult to maintain.Some times in the middle of the coding we will close eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use source control like git?

You can use the [EGit plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/).

If you really want to just save your workspace, you can probably write a script to do that.